# Mail form not working

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I have set a basic mail form in TYPO3 but it doesn't seem to be working.

The installation of TYPO3 I am working on has several sites on it and other existing forms work just fine and don't appear to have any major differences to this new one that doesn't.

When the submit button is clicked the page adds `?tx_form_form[action]=process&cHash=xxx...` to the url and does not send any mail or go to redirect page.

This form appears on the home page, and identical form on an internal page works fine...

Anyone know what might be the problem here?

Generated Form Code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="id-23" id="field-23" action="http://example.com/?tx_form_form[action]=process&amp;cHash=b34b10df4ff74dac67960e990e130408">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="tx_form_form[__referrer][@extension]" value="Form" />
<input type="hidden" name="tx_form_form[__referrer][@vendor]" value="TYPO3\CMS" />
<input type="hidden" name="tx_form_form[__referrer][@controller]" value="Frontend" />
<input type="hidden" name="tx_form_form[__referrer][@action]" value="show" />
<input type="hidden" name="tx_form_form[__referrer][arguments]" value="YToxOntzOjU6Im1vZGVsIjthOjA6e319a4f0ce18ed8a7ca3ab5be6c9bc69bc141296c7da" />
<input type="hidden" name="tx_form_form[__trustedProperties]" value="a:1:{s:7:&quot;tx_form&quot;;a:5:{s:10:&quot;first_name&quot;;i:1;s:9:&quot;last_name&quot;;i:1;s:5:&quot;email&quot;;i:1;s:8:&quot;postcode&quot;;i:1;i:6;i:1;}}bbd972ea3852e6c16fab76a45b46929ac7ab0d52" />
</div>


    <ol>


    <li class="csc-form-24 csc-form-element csc-form-element-textline">
        <label for="field-24">



        </label>

        <input placeholder="First Name" id="field-24" type="text" name="tx_form_form[tx_form][first_name]" required="required" />
    </li>




    <li class="csc-form-25 csc-form-element csc-form-element-textline">
        <label for="field-25">



        </label>

        <input placeholder="Last Name" id="field-25" type="text" name="tx_form_form[tx_form][last_name]" required="required" />
    </li>




    <li class="csc-form-26 csc-form-element csc-form-element-textline">
        <label for="field-26">



        </label>

        <input placeholder="Email" id="field-26" type="text" name="tx_form_form[tx_form][email]" required="required" />
    </li>




    <li class="csc-form-27 csc-form-element csc-form-element-textline">
        <label for="field-27">



        </label>

        <input placeholder="Postal Code" class="signup-sml" id="field-27" type="text" name="tx_form_form[tx_form][postcode]" />
    </li>




    <li class="csc-form-28 csc-form-element csc-form-element-submit">
        <label for="field-28">



        </label>

        <input type="submit" id="field-28" value="Submit" name="tx_form_form[tx_form][6]" />
    </li>



    </ol>
</form>
```

I don't know if it's related but all that extra spacing in the code has been showing up since upgrading the TYPO3 version...

Comment: I tried changing the prefix in case there was a conflict. I can't see many other options to try...

Comment: Do you have a URL to test?

Comment: I can't give out the URL for privacy reasons.

Comment: I suggest to you use powermail with latest version of TYPO3

Comment: Can you post the hole `<form...` code?

Comment: @nbar Edited the question to add this.

Comment: looks fine to me. Have you checked network-console in the dev-console of your browser? Hmm.. I guess the problem is somewhere else. So.. still not enough information

Comment: Just checked firefox network console after submitting. The POST shows there with a status of 200 OK.

Comment: This form is on the Home page, and there is another identical form on the Contact page. The Contact page form works fine... this seems like a big clue.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with a form not being functional in one website and perfectly OK in another.

Setup: TYPO3 7.6 installation with two websites, each with its own domain, both using the builtin system extension form and the extension realurl.

Issue: Within the first website all forms were functional, within the second submitting the form only resulted in the page being reloaded without any validation or action.

Solution:
(1) Make sure that both websites' starting pages are marked as "Root Page" and that both have domain records defined.
(2) Having realurl setup with automatic configuration, I forced an update by deleting the "realurl_autoconf.php" in the "typo3conf" folder.
(3) Make sure that both websites have the correct realurl configuration within their templates' typoscript setup, e.g.:

```
config {
    prefixLocalAnchors = all
    absRefPrefix = http://www.domain.tld/
    absRelPath = /
    tx_realurl_enable = 1
}
```

In my case I'd simply forgotten the www in the absRefPrefix for the second website...

Comment: I never used absRefPrefix with a full scheme and domain definition. In 20+ setups I've just defined absRefPrefix = / and no absRelPath. Just works fine and all my forms are functional. The advantage of not setting a full domain name is that your test and staging systems don't need further configuration domain-wise.